# Updating db using navigation properties of entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

I have following models for my entities, using navigation properties.

```
 [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class l_rate
    {
        public labor_rate()
        {
            this.l_rate_history = new HashSet<l_rate_hist>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int l_rate_id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<l_rate_history> l_rate_history { get; set; }
    }
```

And

```
     [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class l_rate_history
    {

            [DataMember]
        public int l_rate_history_id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
        public decimal rate { get; set; }

        public virtual l_rate l_rate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Using these entities I am reading records following way....

```
    public class testing
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public decimal labo { get; set; }
    }

public class lRateController : ApiController
    {
        private myEntities context = new myEntities();

        // GET api/laborRate
        public IEnumerable<testing> Getl_rate()
        {


            var records = from c in db.l_rate_history select new testing { name = c.l_rate.name, labo = c.rate};

           return records;
        }
```

This works fine to read records. Next I am trying to update or insert new records using same model I have so that i can call

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

Any ideas how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Im not too sure what your problem here is, can you please post your update code?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor basically I am not sure how to save the data back to database. I can read the data fine but dont know how to write it back to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, also check out my article on navigation properties here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first

```
public void Setl_rate_name(int id, string name)
{
    var rate = context.l_rate.Single(r=>r.Id == id);
    rate.name = name;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```